# How to determine whether excel workbook is password protected or not in C# using OLEDB?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I am reading an excel file using **'OLEDB'**. I need a provision where I can determine whether excel file that I am accessing is password protected or not. Please find my code below:

```
private DataSet LoadExcel(string fileName, string tableName)
{
string path = fileName;
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr);
MyConnection.Open();
DataTable dtExcelSchema;
dtExcelSchema = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + SheetName + "]", MyConnection);
MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", tableName);
DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
MyConnection.Close();
return DtSet;
}
```

My code is breaking up on line "MyConnection.Open();" because the excel file which it is accessing here is password-protected. If I could check that, I will bypass the code and display a user-friendly message. Please help if anyone has any idea on this front.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

If the Excel workbook is protected by a password, you cannot open it for data access, even by supplying the correct password with your connection string. If you try, you receive the following error message: "Could not decrypt file."

OLEDB connection will not work for password protected worksheets. If there is some exception, you can detect the exact type and catch it.

Other way is to use the Office API and use the [HasPassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.haspassword%28VS.80%29.aspx) property.

```
Workbook book = '.....xyz''';
if (book.HasPassword) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @Aseem. I am aware of **HasPassword** but due to some limitations I cannot use this property from Excel Interop. Yes try-catch could be a way but I am looking for some exact property or way out from **OLEDB** just like we have it from Excel Interop. The exception I am getting here is pretty common while working with excel files and it can also occur at other instances where file may not be password-protected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sth like that?

```
    try
    {
        MyConnection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: The exception I am getting is pretty common while working with Excel files using **OLEDB**. It can also occur at instances where file may not be password protected. At such times, I cannot popup a password protected message to user from **catch** block.

Comment: Maybe you can verify other possibilities of that error occurring, leaving only password protected issue? (just an idea - haven't checking it)

Answer (score 0):

Per Aseem's first response, the "Could not decrypt file." problem is a result of the Excel file not being in a trusted location.  I had the same problem and solved it by moving the Excel file to a trusted location or adding the folder that the Excel file is in to the Trusted Locations.